# SQL Server left join not returning blank entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to fetch all records from the question table, whether or not they exist in the answer table. There are 50 questions all together, but I am only retrieving 49. What am I doing wrong?

```
select 
    q.question_txt 
from 
    apdev.form_template.question q 
left join 
    apdev.form_submission.answer a on q.question_id = a.question_id
where 
    a.submission_id = 2704336
    and q.form_id = 23
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Classic error.  Condition on all but the first table need to go in the `on` clause:

```
select q.question_txt 
from apdev.form_template.question q left join
     apdev.form_submission.answer a
     on q.question_id = a.question_id and a.submission_id = 2704336
where q.form_id = 23;
```

Why?  The `left join` produces a `NULL` value for `submission_id` in non-matching rows.  The condition `a.submission_id = 2704336` fails.  Although you *could* add `(a.submission_id = 2704336 or a.submission_id is null)`, that doesn't have the same semantics.  It is a good exercise for you to figure out why that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I thought for sure I had tried that.  I must have had something else jacked up.  Thank you very much.